# How make slider work only if is in viewport?

Tags: javascript, slider

**Hello!**
I would to ask, how can I make this slider to work only if slider is on the viewport?

I use this slider: [enter link description here](http://responsiveslides.com/)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Their Javascript does not support it. They do not return the interval that is created, so it cannot be cleared (this is how they pause it). Nor do they have a pause function, except for the one on hover. You will need to update their Javascript to support the ability to pause and play.

Comment: Yes, but I don't how to do it, becasue my JS skills are very bad

Comment: You cannot downvote someone based on an answer that does not make you happy. If you need functionality to be added, ask them on their GitHub.

Comment: I'm asking how to make it by myself. I try modify stop on hover function but I can't do it because I don't know how.